# how do I deal with null in ObjectMapper in swift?

Tags: swift, iphone, objectmapper

I am using ObjectMapper to parse json in swift but it failed on child_menu due to "null". Parsing stop on child_menu and rest of the fields below the child_menu assigned with null values or default values. is there any way to deal with it? Below are the model code. Please help, thanks-

response json -

```
{
               "category_creation_id":"10103",
               "category_id":"1010300000",
               "template_type":"category",
               "list_type":"block-display",
               "menu_set_menu_id":"288",
               "menu_set_id":"4",
               "menu_id":"1030300000",
               "menu_creation_id":"10303",
               "menu_name":"Results",
               "menu_level":"2",
               "num_of_siblings":"0",
               "hierarchical_name":"Companies->Results",
               "menu_parent_id":"222",
               "is_leaf":"N",
               "mobile_display_order":"2",
               "menu_options":"0",
               "is_active":"Y",
               "menu_font_color":null,
               "menu_background_color":null,
               "hover_menu_font_color":null,
               "hover_menu_background_color":null,
               "menu_url":"/companies-results",
               "is_special_menu":"N",
               "new_article_count":"0",
               "child_menu":null
            }
```

response dictionary -

```
{
                    "category_creation_id" = 103;
                    "category_id" = 1030000000;
                    "child_menu" = "<null>";
                    "hover_menu_background_color" = "<null>";
                    "hover_menu_font_color" = "<null>";
                    "is_active" = Y;
                    "is_leaf" = Y;
                    "is_special_menu" = N;
                    "list_type" = "block-display";
                    "menu_background_color" = "<null>";
                    "menu_creation_id" = 10103;
                    "menu_font_color" = "<null>";
                    "menu_id" = 1010300000;
                    "menu_level" = 2;
                    "menu_name" = Test;
                    "menu_options" = 0;
                    "menu_parent_id" = 211;
                    "menu_set_id" = 4;
                    "menu_set_menu_id" = 214;
                    "mobile_display_order" = 5;
                    "new_article_count" = 0;
                    "num_of_siblings" = 0;
                }

struct MenuModel: Mappable {
    // Variable Initializer 
    var menuFontColor: String?
    var menuBackgroundColor: String?
    var hovermenufontcolor : String?
    var menuName = ""
    var hierachyName = ""
    var isActive = false
    var isLeaf = false
    var isSpecialMenu = false
    var menuCreationId = 0
    var menuId: Int64 = 0
    var categoryId: Int64 = 0
    var menuLevel = 0
    var menuOptions = 0
    var menuParentId = 0
    var menuSetId = 0
    var menuSetMenuId = 0
    var menuUrl = ""
    var mobileDisplayOrder = 1
    var numberOfSiblings = 0
    var isExpanded = false
    var subMenus = [MenuModel]()
    var templateType: MenuTemplateType?
    var newArticleCount: Int?
    var listType: String?
    
    init?(map: Map) {
     
    }
  
    
    init() {
    }
    
    init(id: Int64, title: String) {
        self.menuName = title
        self.menuId = id
    }
    /// For mapping of variables with their respective API keys
    /// - Parameter map: Map type object
    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        menuName <- map[APIKey.menuName]
        hierachyName <- map[APIKey.hierarchicalName]
        isActive = (map[APIKey.isActive].currentValue as? String ?? "").uppercased() == "Y"
        isLeaf = (map[APIKey.isLeaf].currentValue as? String ?? "").uppercased() == "Y"
        isSpecialMenu = (map[APIKey.isSpecialMenu].currentValue as? String ?? "").uppercased() == "Y"
        menuCreationId <- map[APIKey.menuCreationId]
        menuId <- map[APIKey.menuId]
        categoryId <- map[APIKey.categoryId]
        menuFontColor <- map[APIKey.menuFontColor]
        menuBackgroundColor <- map[APIKey.menuBackgroundColor]
        hovermenufontcolor <- map[APIKey.hovermenufontcolor]
        menuLevel <- map[APIKey.menuLevel]
        menuOptions <- map[APIKey.menuOptions]
        menuParentId <- map[APIKey.menuParentId]
        menuSetId <- map[APIKey.menuSetId]
        menuSetMenuId <- map[APIKey.menuSetMenuId]
        menuUrl <- map[APIKey.menuUrl]
        mobileDisplayOrder <- map[APIKey.mobileDisplayOrder]
        numberOfSiblings <- map[APIKey.numOfSiblings]
        templateType <- map["template_type"]
        subMenus <- map["child_menu"]
        newArticleCount <- map["new_article_count"]
        listType <- map["list_type"]
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is not JSON so it's hard to say what "<null>" actually is. By the way drop `ObjectMapper` in favor of `Codable`.

Comment: @vadian I have edited the question and added the json, json response have null values. I have to go with ObjectMapper.

Comment: You have to refactor your model anyway because there are no `Int` values at all in the JSON. All numeric values are `String`. And `ObjectMapper` should treat `<null>` as `nil`.

Comment: Use `Codable` instead of `ObjectMapper`. It is much more easier to implement than writing so much code manually.

Comment: If there are `null` then use optional. Don't see why have to use `ObjectMapper`.